# Correct way to initialize pointer to array in C++ ?

Tags: c++, arrays

Consider the code :

```
const int MAX = 3;
int (*array)[MAX]  ;

int intArray[3] = {30 , 40 , 50};

array = &intArray;
for (int h = 0 ; h < MAX ; h++)
{
    std::cout << *(array[h]) << std::endl;
}
```

The output is :

```
30
0
3
```

Clearly something is wrong with the initialization of the array , why do I get 
`30 , 0 , 3` and not `30,40,50`  ?

Comment: Did you mean `(*array)[h]`?`

Comment: In C++ you can use std::array<>

Comment: An array is an alias for a pointer in C++.  While you can have a pointer to a pointer, there’s a good chance you really wanted `int *arrayptr = array;`

Comment: @Lorehead An array is not an alias for a pointer in C++, they are of different types.

Comment: They’re not exactly equivalent in all circumstances, but you can implicitly convert the name of an array to a pointer. `&array[0]` literally does have pointer type, if you need that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like that:

```
const int MAX = 3;
int *array;

int intArray[3] = {30 , 40 , 50};

array = intArray;
for (int h = 0 ; h < MAX ; h++)
{
    std::cout << array[h] << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The handling of built-in arrays in C++ is quite peculiar, especially when considering pointers. A pointer can be seen as one of two things:

- as pointer to a single object
- as pointer to the first element of an array

So how does this work? Well, let's start with the definition of your array, and let's define a pointer to the array in the way it is normally done in C++:

```
const int MAX = 3;
int *array;                           // (1)

int intArray[3] = {30 , 40 , 50};

array = intArray;                     // (2)
for (int h = 0 ; h < MAX ; h++)
{
  std::cout << array[h] << std::endl; // (3)
}
```

Now what is happening here?

At line (1) we define a pointer to `int` named `array`. Note: Not specifically a pointer to array of `int`, but a pointer to plain `int`.

At line (2) we assign `intArray` to that pointer. Now `intArray` is an array, so how can we assign it to a pointer? Well, here comes the magic: If an array is used in an rvalue context (that is, in a context where a value is required), then the compiler actually provides a pointer to the first element. That is, the line is completely equivalent to

```
array = &(intArray[0]);
```

Now in line (3) we access `array[h]`. That is, we access the pointer *as if* it were an array. So what happens here? Well, the pointer is interpreted as pointing to the first element of an array, and the element `h` of that array is accessed. What *actually* happens is that the compiler replaces `array[h]` by `*(array + h)`. That is, it dereferences a pointer that is `h` `int`s later than `array`.

OK, so what does your definition

```
int (*array)[MAX];
```

do? Well, just as the previous declaration defined a pointer to `int`, this defines a pointer to an array of `MAX` `int`s, that is, a pointer to `int[MAX]`. As before, this can point either to a single array of three `int`s, or to an array of such arrays.

Now when you did

```
array = &intArray;
```

you set it to point to the single array `intArray`.

Now in your output line you wrote:

```
*(array[h])
```

So what happens here? Well, in the parentheses you have `array[h]`, that is, you've used the array subscript operator `[]` on the pointer `array`. Therefore the compiler will access the `h`-th array of three ints in your array of arrays of three ints. Now you only have one array of ints there, so as soon as `h > 0` you'll be out of bound. There's absolutely no way to predict the numbers you'll get there (your program could also just have crashed).

However we're not yet finished: Your full expression reads `*(array[h])`, so you actually dereference the result of `array[h]`. But the result of `array[h]` is an array of 3 `int`s! Well, the dereference operator expects a pointer *value*, therefore again the array "decays" to a pointer to its first element, and that of course can be dereferenced, giving the first element of the array. Indeed, you could have equivalently written `*(array[h])` as `array[h][0]`.

And this is also the use case of variables of this type: It would normally be used an variables of the form

```
int intArray[3][3] = {{30, 40, 50}, {300, 400, 500}, {3000, 4000, 5000}};
```

where you would initialize the pointer with `array = intArray` and then your loop would output

```
30
300
3000
```

OK, but how would you access the values of your `intArray` with only three values? Well, for that you have to *first* dereference the pointer in order to get to the array, and *then* access the array index operator:

```
std::cout << (*array)[h] << std::endl;
```

Alternatively you can see it as the first (and only) row of a 1×3 array, and equivalently write

```
std::cout << array[0][h] << std::endl;
```

Comment: From this answer's length and topic, I fully expected it to consist almost entirely of total abject nonsense. I was pleasantly surprised. Good job! +1

Answer (score 1):

```
int (*array)[MAX]  ;
```

This line declare `array` as pointer to array of MAX integers. 
so if you want to print `intArray` using `array` , you can do something like this

```
for (int h = 0; h < MAX; h++)
    {
        std::cout << (*array)[h] << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: `int (*array)[MAX];` is not an array of pointers of size 3. array is a pointer with type `int (*)[MAX]`; An array of pointers of size 3 is  `int* array[MAX];`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `(*array)[h]`. `array` is a pointer to the `intArray`, you should dereference it first.

Since someone thinks that `array` is of array type which is completely wrong. you can verify with the program

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  cout << is_array<int*[3]>::value << endl;
  cout << is_array<int(*)[3]>::value << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: array is not a pointer to intArray, it is an array of pointers.

Comment: @LuciaPasarin  Do you read the program in my answer? `array` is not an array of pointers.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was before looking at the last edit with the code.

Comment: Really useful method to know if a certain type is an array, btw. Why cannot we write int *(array[MAX]) instead of int (*array)[MAX]? It would make it clearer to me that array is a pointer then.

Comment: @LuciaPasarin It's just syntax. but there is some "reason" behind that. when you define an array, you use something like `int a[3];` `a` is an array. `int (*pa)[3];` `pa` is an pointer to array, and `*pa` will be an array conceptually, right?. So `a` and `*pa` should be in the same position in the syntax.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation!